# how is java8 Streams different than collection in java

Tags: java-8

explain the comparison with the example.
can anyone explain to me the line from the book "java8 in Action" ---

> every element in the collection has to be computed before it can be
>   added to the collection.

Comment: what is not clear about this statement?

Comment: "elements have to be computed before becoming part of the collection "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Streams and Collections in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432699/what-is-the-difference-between-streams-and-collections-in-java-8)

Comment: if you want compute you can use `stream.map(" Whatever you want to compute").collect(......);`

Comment: @manfromnowhere my point is I am not clear with the statement mentioned above in case of the collection, but not of the stream in java8.

Comment: @Swati it's better  always define  question clearly .Since no reply so I added this point too even though out of scope.

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi here i am asking for the example to the concept

Answer (score 1):

I like the explanation from the book Java 8 in action, maybe it will help you too understand better the difference:

> For readers who like philosophical viewpoints, you can see a stream as a set of values spread out
>   in time. In contrast, a collection is a set of values spread out in space (here, computer memory),
>   which all exist at a single point in time—and which you access using an iterator to access
>   members inside a for-each loop.

Comment: thank you, sir, for the answer. I actually needed the example to the statement.